# How can I move population to other colonised systems?

Tags: endless-space

I have a very populous home system and other systems with very low food production. How can I transport population from my home system to these other systems?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a colony ship settle on a colonized planet.

Create a colony ship at your home system and send it to the other systems. This will move a pop.